# Don't allow a new user to post an answer identical to one of his/her previous answers

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, spam, duplicate-answers

Sometimes a spammer comes in and posts identical spam answers on random posts.

Maybe we should block this automatically?

Comment: Your first request has merit, but I think that the second would result in a large number of false positives.

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: Rather than not allowing it in the first place, I'd support automatic flagging of such a user for review.  That way it would be easier to identify such spammers for review and possible removal.

Comment: @JeffMercado - There is already an automatic flag raised by community alerting identical on posts

Comment: How many per-user duplicate answers are there that are legitimate?

Comment: @awoodland: I figured there was some threshold before that auto flag gets raised, relatively low for new users and relatively high for more established users.  I actually see it much more often for the established ones than I do for the new ones.  The truly malicious tends to mix it up a bit.

Comment: @Joel I don't see why this is tagged [status-nonrepro] - you can't reproduce that it is possible to post identical answers? [status-declined] I would understand (as "is not necessary").

Comment: "no repro" means that the problem that the OP complained about is not, in fact, a problem. Not because we fixed it (which would be status-completed) but because it was never a problem. Yes, it is possible to post identical answers, but the OP did not request for this to be impossible. They thought this should generate automatic blocking. Which it does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are already flagged and shown to moderators.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize that.